# Why Does Normalize Function Overwrite the Original Variable?

Tags: python, vector

I created a new variable and assigned it a value from another existing variable. But when I try to normalize the new variable, it overwrites the original variable as well. Why does this happen, and how can I fix this problem?

```
import bpy
    
testGeo = bpy.data.objects.new("test", None)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(testGeo)
testGeo.location = (5,7,2)

print('OriginalLoc:', testGeo.location)


test_newLoc = testGeo.location

test_newLoc.normalize()
print('NewLocation:', testGeo.location)
```

The result I got:

OriginalLoc: <Vector (5.0000, 7.0000, 2.0000)>

NewLocation: <Vector (0.5661, 0.7926, 0.2265)>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variable is a name that refers to an object. When you do `x = y`, you make x and y refer to the same object. So if you change that object, both x and y will observe the change. For example

```
y = [1,2,3]
x = y        # x and y refer to the same list
x.append(4)  # change the list
print(x, y)  # same thing
```

---

What you want is either to make a copy of the Vector

```
test_newLoc = testGeo.location.copy()
test_newLoc.normalize()
```

or use `normalized`, which returns a normalized copy without changing the original.

```
test_newLoc = testGeo.location.normalized()
```